# Pipe output to egrep function

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to define a bash function, `highlight`, that I can use to highlight search terms in the output of a previous command. When I do this from the terminal, it works fine as follows:

```
# highlight all occurrences of bar in file foo
cat foo | egrep '(bar|$)'
```

Yes, catting is a simplified example, but it demonstrates how I can do this from the command line. I'd like to use this generically as:  `cat foo | hightlight bar`

From what I've read, I can't simply pipe results to `egrep` like I hoped so I naively tried defining my bash function as:

```
highlight() {
  while read line; do
    pat="'("$1"|$)'"
    echo \"$line\" | egrep $pat
  done
}
```

However, this isn't working. Please advise.

Comment: Note that this will *exclude* any line that does *not* contain the pattern. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quoting is just about entirely wrong.

```
pat="'("$1"|$)'"
```

you include literal single quotes in the pattern, and you're actually *not* quoting the function parameter.

```
echo \"$line\" | egrep $pat
```

You're including literal double quotes in the echo statement, and failing to quote both variables.

This is better:

```
highlight() {
  while read -r line; do
    pat="($1|$)"
    echo "$line" | grep -E "$pat"
  done
}
```

However, grep knows how to read from stdin, so simplify:

```
highlight() { grep -E "($1|$)"; }
```

Comment: So `highlight() { grep -E "($1|$)"; }` certainly seems to work, but I'm baffled as to why `highlight() { egrep '($1|$)'; }` does not.

Comment: When you use single quotes, you are preventing the `$1` variable from expanding.

Comment: 'Your quoting is just about entirely wrong.' I love these motivating comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you read, but it is wrong. `egrep` stands for *extended grep* because it is using the extended POSIX regular expression syntax. It behaves like the standard `grep -E`

Read the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?egrep):

> egrep is the *same* as grep -E

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you should have changed this

```
pat="'("$1"|$)'"
```

To

```
pat="($1|\$)"
```

Also, I don't see the need of "$". In addition, I think it is better to move the initialization of "pat" out of the loop. Here is what I got (tested):

```
#!/bin/bash

function highlight {
    pattern="$1"

    while read line; do
        echo "$line" | egrep --color "$pattern"
    done
}


echo -e 'a\nb\nbar\nhibar' | highlight bar
```